# What do ALSA devices like "hw:0,0" mean? How do I figure out which to use?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I've searched over and over and can't find any explanation of what "hw:0,0" means. How do I determine the number of my USB audio card?  [MPD](http://mpd.wikia.com/) requires me to enter something like this:

```
audio_output {
        type                    "alsa"
        name                    "Sound Card"
        device                  "hw:0,0"     # optional
        format                  "44100:16:2" # optional
}
```

If I do "alsamixer -c 1" it opens the USB card's volume control, but that really doesn't help me.

Where can I find a list of device names/numbers on my system?  Are they resilient to hardware changes?  If I remove card 2, does card 3 become card 2?  Are there other ways to identify devices?  Where can I find documentation for any of this?

Comment: so what ended up working?

Comment: Switching to PulseAudio worked, sort of.  :)  But I had to be logged in locally and modify the audio routing.  Then I decided MPD sucks and gave up.

Comment: Actually "hw:1,0" probably worked, but it said the device was in use (by Pulse?)  I didn't try the other method, but hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

JohnT's answer gives a good basic.  I'll follow it up with how to find the devices on your system.  Use `aplay -l` to get a list of the devices on your system.  The **hw:X,Y** comes from this mapping of your hardware -- in this case, **X** is the **card** number, while **Y** is the **device** number.

```
$ aplay -l   # note lower-case "L" option
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: T71Space [Terratec Aureon 7.1-Space], device 0: ICE1724 [ICE1724]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: T71Space [Terratec Aureon 7.1-Space], device 1: IEC1724 IEC958 [IEC1724 IEC958]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: T71Space [Terratec Aureon 7.1-Space], device 2: ICE1724 Surrounds [ICE1724 Surround PCM]
  Subdevices: 3/3
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
```

---

Since these are USB devices that might not always get the same device numbers each time they're plugged in, the **hw:X,Y** device might change.  The simplest answer is, for a desktop system, try the GNOME/KDE/Xfce configuration tools, and see if they're smart enough to pick up the changes.

The complex way, if you're not doing this with a desktop system, gets ... interesting.  You might be able to get away with using [device aliases](http://alsa.opensrc.org/index.php/DigitalOut#Device_Aliases) instead of the **hw:X,Y** -- this is what the output of `aplay -L` shows.  The **something:CARD=FOO,DEV=Y** stuff is the alias, and probably won't change between different device plug-ins, where the **X** in **hw:X,Y** might.  (Assuming that you're using the same USB dongle each time.)

```
$ aplay -L
default:CARD=CK804
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=CK804,DEV=0                 # hw:0,0
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=CK804,DEV=0            # hw:0,1
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
```

So your aplay command would become `aplay -D front:CARD=CK804,DEV=0 somefile.wav`, and you can use the same devicename in your .asoundrc.

---

If you need something more stable at an even lower level, actual kernel devices, **udev** is what you want -- it's the system that allows for hotplugging devices into the system.  You can [write rules for udev](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) (and here's the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/udev)) that will allow devices to get the same devicename when plugged in.

Comment: Aha! I had been told `aplay -L`, which doesn't provide the same output as `aplay -l`. *sigh*

Comment: How can you tell that `surround40:CARD=CK804,DEV=0` is `hw:0,1`? As far as I can tell it is `hw:0,0` given that it refers to `DEV=0`, but in a different configuration (4 channels rather than 2 as in `front:CARD=CK804,DEV=0`).

Answer (score 24):

`hw:0,0` specifies the default device, on the default sound card. To access your second soundcard's first device, you would specify `hw:1,0`. These are specified in your `.asoundrc`. More on all of this [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc).

Comment: Specifically here: http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#The_naming_of_PCM_devices