# What does sound devices in Linux mean?

Tags: linux, audio

Having read [What do ALSA devices like "hw:0,0" mean? How do I figure out which to use?](https://superuser.com/questions/53957/what-do-alsa-devices-like-hw0-0-mean-how-do-i-figure-out-which-to-use) I'm only more confused.

When I execute on my system:

```
$ aplay -l
```

I get:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

This is just a pretty standard desktop. It has (lspci):

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a2f0
```

and:

```
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

So I have two audio devices. That seems to be about right, since aplay lists card 0 and card 1.

I can even understand that there is one analog and one digital device on card 0, but what is the difference between device 3, 7, and 8 on card 1?

Answer (score 0):

HDMI port can transfer audio.
It looks like you graphic card has 3 HDMI port, hence 3 devices on card 1(Nvidia card).

Comment: Actually my graphics card has only 2x DVI, no HDMI at all. The integrated graphics card has 1x HDMI, 1x DVI, and 1x VGA.